# $X$ is the midpoint of $PQ$, $O$ is an arbitrary point. Show that $OX=\frac{1}{2}(OP+OQ)$?

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

I solved the following exercise:

> [image]

With a technique that perhaps is a bit questionable. I've seen the original proof of it which takes into account the relation $OX=OP+PX$ but I did something a little bit different:

- $PQ:=P-Q$
- $X=\frac{1}{2}PQ=\frac{1}{2}(P-Q)$
- $OX=O-X = O-\frac{1}{2}(P-Q)$
- If $O-\frac{1}{2}(P-Q)=\frac{1}{2}(OP+OQ)$, then I should be able to cancel both sides (uniqueness of inverse?). Then:

$$O-\frac{1}{2}(P-Q)\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{2}(OP-OQ)\\2O-(P-Q)\stackrel{?}{=}(OP-OQ)\\O+O-P-Q\stackrel{?}{=}(O-P+(O-Q))\\O+O-P-Q\stackrel{?}{=}(O-P+O-Q)\\O+O-P-Q\stackrel{!}{=}O+O-P-Q$$

Is this acceptable?

Comment: "$PQ:=P-Q$": assuming $P,Q$ are shorthand for the position vectors $OP,OQ$ the relation is reversed, it should be $PQ=Q-P\,$. "$X=\frac{1}{2}PQ$": no, what does in fact hold true is that $PX=\frac{1}{2}PQ$.

Comment: If $P$ means $OP$ and $Q$ means $OP$ what does $O$ mean? The zero vector?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales $O$ is an arbitrary vector.

Comment: @dxiv $PQ$ represents the vector from $P$ to $Q$.

Comment: @AskYourself That much could be guessed, but what is $P$ if not $OP\,$? And, if $P$ *is* in fact shorthand for $OP\,$, then again the very first step is wrong, since $PQ = OQ - OP \ne P - Q\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Wait. There is something confusing: I pictured $P$ as the vector that goes from the origin to $P$. And you are telling me that $P$ is a shorthand for $OP$ and $O$ is not necessarily the origin (given in the question). So, in this case, are we not taking the existence of the origin into consideration?

Comment: I also must confess that I always found the vector arithmetic _at this level_ a bit confusing. I feel that the point where the confusion is cleared up is when we have a basis. I think there is a _level_ in which people talk about directed line segments in which there are confusing manipulations such as $OX=OP+PX$. I had to draw it to see it "happening".

Comment: @AskYourself *You* have to define your terms, even more so when using confusing notation such as $O$ for an arbitrary point which is *not* the origin. Assume then that the origin is some point $K\,$, and $P,Q$ stand for the position vectors $KP,KQ\,$. My original comment still stands as written that you've got the first step backwards, since $PQ=KQ-KP=Q-P \,\ne\, P-Q=KP-KQ=QP\,$.

Answer (score 2):

[image: vector problem[1]]

If $X$ is the midpoint of segment $PQ$ then

$$\vec{PX}+\vec{QX}=\vec{0}\tag{1}$$

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{OP}+\vec{PX}&=&\vec{OX}\\
\vec{OX}-\vec{PX}&=&\vec{OP}\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{OQ}+\vec{QX}&=&\vec{OX}\\
\vec{OX}-\vec{QX}&=&\vec{OQ}\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

Adding equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives

\begin{eqnarray}
2\vec{OX}-(\vec{PX}+\vec{QX})&=&\vec{OP}+\vec{OQ}\\
2\vec{OX}-\vec{0}&=&\vec{OP}+\vec{OQ}\\
\vec{OX}&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{OP}+\vec{OQ}\right)
\end{eqnarray}